# Configure flume in shell/bash script - avoid interactive flume shell console

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, flume

The normal way you configure flume is via flume master web console, way easy to talk about it here.

OR

via interactive flume shell console, follow the steps below:

```
1. $ flume shell   //this brings you to the interactive flume shell console
2. in the interactive console,connect flume-master-node   // this connects you to flume-master
3. in the interactive console, run "exec unconfig your_node"  // this unconfig all flume configuration 
4. in the interactive console, run "exec config your_node new_config"    // apply new flume configuration
5. quit  // exit the the interactive console
```

So far so good.

Then I am trying to write a bash script for my flume configuration.
so I want to squeeze 1,2,3,4,5 into a bash and it runs automatically every time without intervention, something like this:

```
/usr/bin/flume shell << EOF         #line1
connect $FLUME_MASTER               #line2

exec unconfig your_node             #line3
exec config your_node new_config    #line4

quit                                #line5

EOF                                 #line6
```

But everytime I run this bash script it always stops at **#line1** and brings me to interactive flume shell console instead of running it sliently in a non-iteractive mode.

Does anybody know how to ignore the interactive mode and just run it sliently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow followed flume user guide [flume/UserGuide_using_the_flume_command_shell](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/flume/UserGuide/#_using_the_flume_command_shell):

```
echo "connect localhost:35873\ngetconfigs\nquit" | flume shell -q
```

this doesn't work if you put it in a bash script. But I got way with it by doing this:

```
/usr/bin/flume shell -q << EOF 

connect localhost:35873

getconfigs

quit

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-q` option to `flume` to see if that helps.