# Avoid interactive mode in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

There is an interactive shell console, I can get into it, run specific set of commands inside the console and exit from it.

Now I want to write a bash script that connects to an interactive shell console and runs my commands silently, exits at the end without any interaction. This means I want to have everything automated in a non-interactive way. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

I am trying something like, say, blabla shell is the interactive console here, it always bring me to the interactive mode :(

```
/usr/bin/blabla shell << EOF 
do A,
do B,
do C
quit
EOF
```

I have a long/specific version of this question can be found here ->
[Configure flume in shell/bash script - avoid interactive flume shell console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10850986/1275937)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing `stdin` should do the trick:

```
exec <&-
```

Comment: thanks for the response, in my case, should it be /usr/bin/blabla shell <&- << EOF  ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/flume/UserGuide/#_using_the_flume_command_shell) you can pass commands to the shell via `echo "connect localhost:35873\ngetconfigs\nquit" | flume shell -q`

Comment: just FYI, I post my answer for running flume configuration in silent mode in another question I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The `expect` command if your friend. It can emulate interactive communication with other commands even in very sophisticated way.

From [man expect](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/expect.1.html):

> Expect  is  a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the commands you would input in the interactive prompt into a file, then run the command like:

```
command < file
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the *Secure SHell*, `ssh` does what you need. It requires that the "remote" machine is configured as an SSH server. I use it regularly to run commands on other hosts, such as

```
 ssh user@host command
```